# Texturing Cubes

Tags: java, 3d, textures

How can I texture a cube that is able to rotate in x,y and z direction in pure Java?
Here is what i have tried:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Cube extends JFrame {

// 8 Vertices 1-8
double p[][] = new double[9][4];

int x=1, y=2, z=3;

boolean xRotUp = false;
boolean yRotRight = false;
boolean xRotDown = false;
boolean yRotLeft = false;
boolean zRotLeft = false;
boolean zRotRight = false;
boolean moveLeft = false;
boolean moveRight = false;
boolean moveUp = false;
boolean moveDown = false;

Image tex = Textures.getTexture("dirt_side");


double px, py, pz;

double angle_x = 0.002;
double angle_y = 0.00150;
double angle_z = 0.0010; 


public Wuerfel() {
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            //ROTATION
            case 37:
                yRotLeft = false;
                break;
            case 38:
                xRotUp = false;
                break;
            case 39:
                yRotRight = false;
                break;
            case 40:
                xRotDown = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                moveUp = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                moveDown = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                moveLeft = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                moveRight = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_Q:
                zRotLeft = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_E:
                zRotRight = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                //ROTATION
                case 37:
                    if (!yRotRight) {
                    yRotLeft = true;
                    } else {
                        yRotRight = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 38:
                    if (!xRotDown) {
                    xRotUp = true;
                    } else {
                        xRotDown = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 39:
                    if (!yRotLeft) {
                    yRotRight = true;
                    } else {
                        yRotLeft = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 40:
                    if (!xRotUp) {
                    xRotDown = true;
                    } else {
                        xRotUp = false;
                    }
                    break;
                    //MOVE
                case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                    moveUp = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                    moveDown = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                    moveLeft = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                    moveRight = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_Q:
                    zRotLeft = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_E:
                    zRotRight = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

public void move() {
    for (int i=1; i<9;i++) {
        px = p[i][x];
        py = p[i][y];
        pz = p[i][z];
        if (moveUp) {
            p[i][y]-=0.1;
        }

        if (moveDown) {
            p[i][y]+=0.1;
        }

        if (moveLeft) {
            p[i][x]-=0.1;
            p[i][z]-=0.1;
        } 
        if (moveRight) {
            p[i][x]+=0.1;
            p[i][z]+=0.1;
        }

    }
}

public void rotate() {
    for (int i=0; i<9;i++) {
        px = p[i][x];
        py = p[i][y];
        pz = p[i][z];
        if (xRotUp) {
            p[i][y] = py*Math.cos(angle_x)-pz*Math.sin(angle_x);
            p[i][z] = py*Math.sin(angle_x)+pz*Math.cos(angle_x);

            py = p[i][y];
            pz = p[i][z];
        }

        if (xRotDown) {
             p[i][y] = py*Math.cos(-angle_x)-pz*Math.sin(-angle_x);
                p[i][z] = py*Math.sin(-angle_x)+pz*Math.cos(-angle_x);

                py = p[i][y];
                pz = p[i][z];
        }

        if (yRotRight) {
            p[i][x] = px*Math.cos(angle_y)+pz*Math.sin(angle_y);
            p[i][z] =-px*Math.sin(angle_y)+pz*Math.cos(angle_y);

            px = p[i][x];
        }

        if (yRotLeft) {
            p[i][x] = px*Math.cos(-angle_y)+pz*Math.sin(-angle_y);
            p[i][z] =-px*Math.sin(-angle_y)+pz*Math.cos(-angle_y);

            px = p[i][x];
        }

        if (zRotRight) {
            p[i][x] = px*Math.cos(angle_z)-py*Math.sin(angle_z);
            p[i][y] = py*Math.cos(angle_z)+px*Math.sin(angle_z);
        }
        if (zRotLeft) {
            p[i][x] = px*Math.cos(-angle_z)-py*Math.sin(-angle_z);
            p[i][y] = py*Math.cos(-angle_z)+px*Math.sin(-angle_z);
        }
    }
}

public void init() {
    setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));

    // 8 vertices in local matrix
    p[1][x] = -100; p[1][y] = -100; p[1][z] = -100;
    p[2][x] = +100; p[2][y] = -100; p[2][z] = -100;
    p[3][x] = +100; p[3][y] = -100; p[3][z] = +100;
    p[4][x] = -100; p[4][y] = -100; p[4][z] = +100;
    p[5][x] = -100; p[5][y] = +100; p[5][z] = -100;
    p[6][x] = +100; p[6][y] = +100; p[6][z] = -100;
    p[7][x] = +100; p[7][y] = +100; p[7][z] = +100;
    p[8][x] = -100; p[8][y] = +100; p[8][z] = +100;

    //       8 - - - - - 7
    //     / |         / |
    //    5 - - - - - 6  |
    //    |  |        |  |
    //    |  4 - - - -|- 3
    //    | /         | /
    //    1 - - - - - 2
}

Image buffer;
Graphics2D gBuffer;

double Frames = 0;
double FPS = 0.0;
double Starttime = 0;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // Double-Buffering
    if (buffer==null) {
        buffer=createImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
        gBuffer=(Graphics2D)buffer.getGraphics();
    }
    gBuffer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    gBuffer.clearRect(0,0,this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

    //FPS
    if (System.currentTimeMillis()-Starttime>=1000) {
        Starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        FPS = Frames;
        Frames = 0;
    } else {
        Frames++;
    }

    // Antialiasing
    gBuffer.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    // Local cube vertices in global matrix +200
    gBuffer.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    /*
    gBuffer.fillPolygon(new int[] {
            (int)p[1][x]+200,
            (int)p[2][x]+200,
            (int)p[6][x]+200,
            (int)p[5][x]+200},
                new int[] {
            (int)p[1][y]+200,
            (int)p[2][y]+200,
            (int)p[6][y]+200,
            (int)p[5][y]+200
                } , 4);
                */

    // texturing THE PART THAT DOES NOT WORK
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.addPoint((int)p[1][x]+200, (int)p[1][y]+200);
    polygon.addPoint((int)p[2][x]+200, (int)p[2][y]+200);
    polygon.addPoint((int)p[6][x]+200, (int)p[6][y]+200);
    polygon.addPoint((int)p[5][x]+200, (int)p[5][y]+200);

    gBuffer.setClip(polygon);
    gBuffer.drawImage(tex, (int)p[1][x]+200, (int)p[1][y]+200, null);
    gBuffer.setClip(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()));


    //Wireframe
    gBuffer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[1][x])+200,(int)(p[1][y])+200,(int)(p[2][x])+200,(int)(p[2][y])+200);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[2][x])+200,(int)(p[2][y])+200,(int)(p[3][x])+200,(int)(p[3][y])+200);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[3][x])+200,(int)(p[3][y])+200,(int)(p[4][x])+200,(int)(p[4][y])+200);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[4][x])+200,(int)(p[4][y])+200,(int)(p[1][x])+200,(int)(p[1][y])+200);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[5][x])+200,(int)(p[5][y])+200,(int)(p[6][x])+200,(int)(p[6][y])+200);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[6][x])+200,(int)(p[6][y])+200,(int)(p[7][x])+200,(int)(p[7][y])+200);
    gBuffer.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[7][x])+200,(int)(p[7][y])+200,(int)(p[8][x])+200,(int)(p[8][y])+200);
    gBuffer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[8][x])+200,(int)(p[8][y])+200,(int)(p[5][x])+200,(int)(p[5][y])+200);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[1][x])+200,(int)(p[1][y])+200,(int)(p[5][x])+200,(int)(p[5][y])+200);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[2][x])+200,(int)(p[2][y])+200,(int)(p[6][x])+200,(int)(p[6][y])+200);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[3][x])+200,(int)(p[3][y])+200,(int)(p[7][x])+200,(int)(p[7][y])+200);
    gBuffer.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    gBuffer.drawLine((int)(p[4][x])+200,(int)(p[4][y])+200,(int)(p[8][x])+200,(int)(p[8][y])+200);


    g.drawImage (buffer, 0, 0, this);







    rotate();
    move();

    repaint();
}


public void update(Graphics g) {paint(g);}
}
```

And here are the results:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKwdHAzGReo&list=PLibL_cUAIdkBcCkFWe0qsEcPKhxxnaxdL

okay...i know I've done some things in this code which I should have done differently but this class is for test purposes only.

Comment: A little confused - you say cube & tagged this as 3D, but your code looks to be 2D.  This post covers setting the [Texture/background Image for polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632411/texture-background-image-for-polygon) if that's what you're after; if not, you'll need to edit/clarify your question.

Comment: @Pikalek ok here is my whole cube class;i hope this helps

Comment: "I already tried something but it doesn't really work" This question would be clearer if you summarised **what** you've already tried and **in what ways** it's failing to achieve your goals. Right now a user would have to read your whole source code and run it in their head to be able to guess what your problem is, and that presents a significant barrier which is likely to limit the number & quality of answers you get. Make it as easy as possible for someone to get your problem (pictures/videos often help!) and you'll get better answers, faster.

Comment: @Clyme If you want to create 3d graphics you might want to consider using a 3d graphics API.

Comment: @Philipp I know, it would be easier and probably faster but like I already said in my question i want to do it in pure Java.I think it's far more fun to do everything on my own instead of using pre-coded APIs.